# Is it possible to use windows authentication to connect to SSAS cube through Python?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, ssas, windows-authentication, cube

I am new to this field. I've tried to do it using olap.py but in that case database credentials are required. Is there any way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The *only* way to connect to SSAS is using a Trusted Connection.

Comment: But can we authenticate the user using windows authentication?